# Nodejs save binary file using stream

Tags: node.js, excel, stream, binary, filestream

Greeting all,

I'm trying to use stream to save data object into an Excel file. However, the file couldn't be opened after saving.

At the same time, I use fs.writeFile to save the same data object, and the Excel file could be opened and viewed correctly.

Please see the code below. When I compared the two files, the one saved with Stream was about 2kb larger, and if i remove the "binary" parameter, the fs.writeFile won't work either, so I think the "binary" was doing the magic.

Could you let me know what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = 'temp',
    Stream = require('stream'),
    rs = new Stream.Readable({ objectMode: true }),
    outFileStream,
    result = generateExcelData();

    rs.push(result);
    rs.push(null);
    outFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path + 'stream.xlsx');//stream.xlsx cannot be opened 
    rs.pipe(outFileStream);

    fs.writeFile(path + 'stream2.xlsx', result, 'binary');//stream2.xlsx can be opened without any issue
```

Comment: Why are you using a stream (in `objectMode` even) just to write the result to a file? Why not just write the data directly? Also, what kind of value is `result`? A Buffer? A string? Something else?

Comment: @mscdex: the reason i wanted to use stream is because the data could potentially be very big -- it's an array of json objects. There was a couple of times I got memory exceeding error. So i was trying to use stream. Thanks

Comment: Well instead of generating one large data set, you might consider using [`JSONStream.stringify()`](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream#jsonstreamstringifyopen-sep-close) and pushing each array element to it. Then pipe that to `outFileStream`.

Comment: Thanks, i got it to work with following: buffer = new Buffer(result, 'binary');

Answer (score 0):

I realized i missed this:

buffer = new Buffer(result, 'binary');